# How to know that specific process is running in python?

Tags: python, process, subprocess

After receiving alarms from web cameras i execute a command to see 15 seconds of the live stream of every camera that has active alarm. 
my code is simple:

```
if alarms:
#this is working and the cameras are displayed for 15 seconds
p=subprocess.Popen(["cvlc","rtsp://IP_ALARM:554","--run-time=15","--stop-time=15","vlc://quit"])
```

I just want to know how to prevent to display the same camera more than one time.

If i have two alarms from the same camera this camera will be displayed two times. In alarms i have indexes of every camera.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you differenciate between camaras, with the port 554?

Comment: hello lapinkoira, in alarms i have index for the camera that have active alarm. it's the IP of the camera. if index==1 then camera IP=192.168.0.1 etc

Comment: Can I see an example of alarms? how doest if alarms works if its a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont add arguments to the command?

```
alarms = [{'ip': '192.168.0.1', 'offline': True}]
for alarm in alarms:
    if alarm['offline']:
        #this is working and the cameras are displayed for 15 seconds
        p=subprocess.Popen(["cvlc","rtsp://%s:554","--run-time=15","--stop-time=15","vlc://quit"] % alarm['ip'])
```